# Make Postgresql.Simple query results available to rest of .hs file

Tags: haskell

I have a sensor that puts values in a postgres table and im using postgresql-simple to read them out in my `main :: IO ()` function with `return queryResult` after `queryResult <- mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "select sensor1 from lightbool" :: IO [Only String])`.

I need to convert these values with another function (`lightBoolHandler`). It needs to take the contents of a query -- which are fake "bools" that are actually strings -- and produce safely typed Haskell `[Bool]`.

How can i make the contents/result of that IO action availble to other parts of the .hs file?

Script snippet:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- connectPostgreSQL "host=myHost.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 user=myUser password=myPw dbname=myDBName"
  queryResult <- mapM_ print =<< (query_ conn "select sensor1 from lightbool" :: IO [Only String])
  return queryResult

lightBoolHandler :: [Only String] -> [Bool]
lightBoolHandler list = ?
```

For reference, if I run `main` in ghci, this is what I get:

```
Only {fromOnly = "TRUE"}
Only {fromOnly = "TRUE"}
Only {fromOnly = "TRUE"}
Only {fromOnly = "TRUE"}
Only {fromOnly = "FALSE"}
Only {fromOnly = "FALSE"}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to muddy the waters with a database example.  How do you pass values from one function to another in Haskell regardless of their source?  You pass the value as an argument in a function call. 
 Consider:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  queryResult <- return ["True", "False"]
  mapM_ print queryResult
  let parsedResults = lightBoolHandler queryResult
  mapM_ print parsedResults

lightBoolHandler :: [String] -> [Bool]
lightBoolHandler = map read
```

**Side Notes**

```
queryResult <- mapM_ print =<< ...
```

Calling this a "result" is misleading.  Your `mapM_` means "ignore the result and return `()`.  More, the result of `print` is not interesting.  presumably you would remove that part when developing and instead:

```
queryResult <- query ...
mapM_ print queryResult
let bools = lightBoolHandler queryResult
... use bools somehow ...
```

Comment: Thanks!  I think I have adapted my script well with your suggestions.  However, I am still stuck on the fact that `lightBoolHandler :: [String] -> [Bool]` really needs to be able to be `lightBoolHandler :: [Only String] -> [Bool]`.  How would I adapt that function?

Comment: I am trying things along these lines, though without much luck: `lightBoolHandler = fmap (read . fromOnly)`

Comment: I can get it out of the `Only` with `lightBoolOnlyRemover = map fromOnly`.  But I cannot figure out how to also apply `read` to get it to become a true `Bool`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - that's one of the first things I tried, but it returns values in the `Only` (e.g. `Only {fromOnly = "TRUE"}`) and then ends with this message: `"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

Comment: Here's a hint: what does `read "TRUE"` return? How about `read "False"`? Make sure to copy text from my comment EXACTLY, do not retype it.

Comment: Both of those examples return `*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse`

Comment: I was able to get to `"FALSE"` and `"TRUE"` outputs (as a list) with this `map (read . show . fromOnly)`.  Now, trying to get those to true `Bool`s.  I guess with pattern matching?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - I ended up doing this (the custom function is a pattern match).  Not elegant, but it works - `map (lightBoolString2Bool . read . show . fromOnly)`.  Thanks for the help :)